# ERROR: Firebase Auth Failed : FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/popup-closed-by-user)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I am using firebase auth in order to signup a user onto my platform. However, when the popup for firebase opens, it shows the following error in the console and the auth fails.

```sh
[ERROR] Firebase Auth Failed : FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/popup-closed-by-user)
```

Could someone help me with this? What exactly is the issue and how may I rectify it?

*Note*: I have added the domain to Authentication > Sign-in method > Authorized Domains as well. Still, it does not work.